# Do buzzing and chirping noises indicate a failing refrigerator?

Tags: repair, refrigerator, replacement, noise, compressor

My refrigerator was starting to run loud a few months ago. It was very over due for a cleaning - afterwards it wasn't as loud.

Today it started to chirp at me and make a general high pitched noise. It gets slightly quieter as it continues to run. I'm pretty sure the noise is coming from the compressor. Sometimes it almost sounds like an alarm clock going off in there or a bell.

Is the compressor faulty or could the noise be caused by something else?

It's a Whirlpool. I believe purchased (by previous owner) around 2016, I don't think there's a warranty.

https://youtube.com/shorts/0UzSmxDUUmM?feature=share

https://youtu.be/9-dtE0qOGTI

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try disconnecting the fan and see if the noise goes away.